# React: How do i fix "Maximum update depth exceeded error"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 modals and they are similar. One of works but the other one sometimes works sometimes doesn't. Both codes are same just the models is different but i coulnd't find any result.

This is error;
**`Error`**: `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

```
174 | }
  175 | setVals(data.form);
  176 | 
  177 | setInputList(
      | ^  178 |   JSON.parse(data.form.cabinTeam, data.form.cabinTeamLicence)
  179 | );
```

This is code;

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setDisabled(false);
    setVals(initVals);
    setInputList([{ cabinTeam: "", cabinTeamLicence: "" }]);
    if (id) {
      axios.get(`/twoA/${id}`).then(({ data }) => {
        if (data.form !== null && data.form !== undefined) {
          if (data.form.opearationDate !== null) {
            data.form.opearationDate = moment(data.form.opearationDate).format(
              "DD/MM/YYYY"
            );
          }
          setVals(data.form);

          setInputList(
            JSON.parse(data.form.cabinTeam, data.form.cabinTeamLicence)
          );

          setDisabled(true);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [id]);
  

  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([
    { cabinTeam: "", cabinTeamLicence: "" },
  ]);

  const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setInputList(list);
  };

  const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    const list = [...inputList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setInputList(list);
  };

  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setInputList([...inputList, { cabinTeam: "", cabinTeamLicence: "" }]);
  };
```

Comment: Are the words "modals" and "models" used correctly? Could one have a typo?

Comment: the error is caused by useEffect maybe you're changing the id inside you're useEffect hook

Comment: Where do you get `id` from?

Comment: I'm getting id from edit form.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    if (!id) {
      onHide();
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [id]);

  // looking for loading/dispatch
  useEffect(() => {}, [isLoading, dispatch]);

  const saveTwoA = (values) => {
    axios.post(`/twoA/${id}`, values);
  };
  const intl = useIntl();